# Is the 2 to 1 MUX universal?

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer

Is the 2 to 1 multiplexer universal? Can it create a 7 to 1 multiplexer by multiplying its logic circuit?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It is **not** universal by itself. Here is how you can implement the AND and OR gates using it:

(I am going to use the more conventional notation - I.e. the `s` for the selector, `d0` for the first data input and `d1` for the second)

The general function of such a MUX is

```
f = s'.d0 + s.d1
```

If `s=a`, `d0=a` and `d1=b` you get

```
f = a'.a + a.b = a.b
```

Which is AND function.

If `s=a`, `d0=b` and `d1=a` you get

```
f = a'.b + a.a = a'.b + a = a + b
```

Which is the OR function.

There is no way to implement the NOT function though. But! if you can use constants in addition, then it becomes possible:

If `s=a`, `d0=1` and `d1=0` you get

```
f = s'.1 + s.0 = s'
```

Which is the NOT function.